# When can one say that one thing is directly proportional to another?

Tags: terminology, mathematics

For example, consider
$$ y=\frac{x}{\cos \theta} $$
and 
$$ L=y \sin\theta . $$

I derived a relation for a net force 
$$ F_{net}=\frac{4kx^3}{y(y+1)} . $$
Can I say that the force is directly proportional to $x^3$?, as if I am substituting the value of $y$, then $x$ gets canceled out and I get a new relation.

Sorry: I couldn't think of any tags for this question.

Comment: In general the lack of appropriate tags is a marker for a question that might not be on topic.

Comment: This sounds like more of a question for http://math.stackexchange.com/, as it's more about mathematical nomenclature than physics.

Comment: As written now, I think this is a perfectly good and clear question.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot say that $F$ is proportional to $x^3$ because $y$ and $\theta$ also depend on $x$. You need to substitute to remove all of the interdependence between $y$ and $x$.

$x=y\cos\theta$
$L=y\sin\theta$
$x^2+L^2=y^2$
$y(y+1)=y^2+y=x^2+L^2+\sqrt{x^2+L^2}$